# LINQ to SQL - Extensibility method definitions missing

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

I have just had to use LINQ to SQL on an SQL Server 2000 database and I have noticed that it does not include all the "Extensibility Method Definitions" actions, why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly is missing? What are you seeing (or not)?

In particular, LINQ-to-SQL's strategy for the database (i.e. how to do paging etc on SQL2000 vs SQL2005 etc) is chosen at *runtime* based on the connection and the specific server (so it updates automatically when you install SQL Server 2008).

The code generation is based purely on the dbml, which doesn't really care about the server version (it is just xml - take a look).

If you are missing some `partial` methods, I wonder if you haven't accidentally detached your `partial class`es from the dbml-generated ones, perhaps by changing the namespace or their names.

Comment: I have the same table in two different database a SQL 2000 and SQL 2008, and here is the resulting generated code, you will notices that in the SQL 2000 version it is missing the Extensibility Method Definitions region

http://www.bryanavery.co.uk/file.axd?file=2009%2f8%2fDataClasses1.designer.cs

I have tried doing this on a smaller table and it appears to work okay, so what is wrong with this one?

Comment: Okay, found it my SQL 2000 table did not have a primary key, and as such the Extensibility Method Definitions was not created.

After adding a Primary key the Extensibility Method Definitions come in.

Answer (score 3):

Extensibility methods are only generated for tables/entities with primary keys ([source](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a5402b43-ed4c-4f74-82f3-b9135e71e5f9/extensibility-methods-missing?forum=linqtosql)).

Note that this also applies to SQL Views.

After dropping an entity onto the Linq to SQL designer you can nominate a column as the primary key in the Properties window. Regenerate the designer.cs file and the extensibility methods will now be created.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Scott Guthrie](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/29/linq-to-sql-part-2-defining-our-data-model-classes.aspx):

> LINQ to SQL will support SQL 2000. 
>   One feature that requires SQL 2005 is
>   the server-side paging support (where
>   you only do the paging in the
>   database).  This uses the SQL 2005
>   ROW_NUMBER() feature which is only in
>   SQL 2005

Comment: Okay, that sounds good, so where has the Extensibility Method Definitions gone?